# Using ASP.Net templates outside of ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, aspnet-compiler

As a brief intro, I spent the last few days writing my own template parser/compiler. It's been an interesting project (which I plan to continue) but it sparked some curiosity about how ASP.Net (ASPX, MVC 2/3, or otherwise) handles templates and whether it's modular enough to use in different projects. There also doesn't seem to be much discussion on the topic, so why not ask?

ASP.Net has a lot of nice features:

- It's a proven system that works well in production
- Templates are compiled to MSIL
- It recognizes that files change and recompiles
- Great debugging support
- Extensible templates

So here's a question: **is it possible to take the template parsing/compiling/debugging system and reuse it for an entirely different purpose?** Is it modular, or is it kind of that's-all-that-asp.net-is and you either get it or you don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASPX WebForms pages are not quite flexible enough for general use.
It's possible, but it's a lot of headache.  (I've done it)

The new Razor engine is extremely flexible; look at the [RazorEngine project](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) for general purpose use.

However, some of the features you're describing (file change monitoring) are part of ASP.Net itself, not Razor, and will only work in an ASP.Net AppDomain.